# How can I make Qt CMake project link in Xcode for an i386 architecture?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, qt, cmake

I have developed an application that works on Windows and I'm now trying to get it to compile for Mac. I've tried to keep everything portable, using Qt with CMake and the library Cinder but inevitably it is not turning out to be that simple.

I'm running Xcode 4.4.1 on Mac OS 10.7.5 and Qt 4.8.3 - I'm also using the LGPL licence of Qt which requires me to use dynamic rather than static linking. I downloaded Qt as an installer from http://qt-project.org/downloads and have not compiled it myself (nor am I entirely certain how to do so on a Mac).

Using CMake to create an Xcode project and with a bit of tweaking I've managed to get to the compile stage but I'm stuck with this line which then causes all Qt linkages to fail:

*ignoring file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/Library/Frameworks/QtXml.framework/QtXml, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0xcf 0xfa 0xed 0xfe 0x 7 0x 0 0x 0 0x 1 0x 3 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 6 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 ) which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/Library/Frameworks/QtXml.framework/QtXmlignoring file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/Library/Frameworks/QtCore.framework/QtCore, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0xcf 0xfa 0xed 0xfe 0x 7 0x 0 0x 0 0x 1 0x 3 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 6 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 ) which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/Library/Frameworks/QtCore.framework/QtCore*

It's also worth mentioning that I need to build for 32 bit architecture (i386) with the 10.6 SDK for compatibility with Cinder.

So, the question is, how can I get past this error? I gather that the problem may be that Qt has been built only for 64 bit architecture but how do I build the right version and point my Xcode project to it?